# Can these simple HtmlHelpers be optimized?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have these to Helper Methods:

```
@AdminHelper.BeginLeftMenu()

    <a href="#">content</a>

@AdminHelper.EndLeftMenu()
```

Is it possible to make it look more like:

```
@AdminHelper.LeftMenu() {

    <a href="#">content</a>

}
```

Instead, and what would it looke like in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about making it look like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginLeftMenu())
{
    <a href="#">content</a>
}
```

which would generate for example:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">content</a>
</li>
```

You could have implemented it like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    private class Menu : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TextWriter _writer;
        public Menu(TextWriter writer)
        {
            _writer = writer;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _writer.Write("</li>");
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable BeginLeftMenu(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var writer = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer;
        writer.Write("<li>");
        return new Menu(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just what i was looking for! thank you! Whay is _write of type TextWriter and not a string or HtmlString? And woulnd't it be a good idea to make properties for BeginHtml and EndHtml so it can be for other purposes aswell?

Comment: @BjarkeCK, it's `TextWriter` because that's what `htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer` is - a TextWriter which allows you to write to the view output. As far as your question about the Begin and End methods is concerned, I cannot answer it because I don't know anything about your scenario and what you are trying to achieve. So the best answer I can give you is: it depends.

Comment: Super! I'll play around with it :=) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can handle this.

1) You can create Extension method to HtmlHelper as below.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString CreateListLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string href, string linkName)
    {
       return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("<li><a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a></li>", href, linkName));                    
    }
```

and you can use it as below

```
@Html.CreateListLink("javascript:alert('yada yada yada')", "Test Me")
```

Which will generate html text like this

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:alert('yada yada yada')">Test Me</a>
</li>
```

2) You can be more fancy with new features of Asp.net MVC and use @helper razor syntax

```
@helper MyHelper(string href, string linkName){          
        <li><a href="@href">@linkName</a></li>;          
      }
 @MyHelper("javascript:alert('I am from razor..!!')", "hi")
```

You can also create App_Code folder and all extention.cshtml under that folder and add above helper in the file.

More Details: http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-3/mvc-3-razor-helpers